# VSCode Jupiter notebook cannot resolve import for package installed in editable (-e) mode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conda, pylance

I am using a Jupyter notebook running in VSCode to test some ideas for a work project and I am using a package that is in a private GitHub repo. I encountered certain conflicts with versions of jax and numpy and after some fiddling trying to fix the issues, I simply re-installed said package to make sure I was using the correct versions of all required packages. Everything seemed fine until I re-opened the notebook and found a bunch of `Import "<package name>" could not be resolved Pylance`.

The imports still work and the code runs, however, PyLance appears not to be "seeing" said package.

I am using a conda Python 3.8 environment and to re-install the package I ran

```
pip install -e . --force-reinstall
```

I have also tried un-installing and re-installing the package, as well as creating a brand new conda env, and then installing the package there. Neither of these options worked however and I was stuck with the same issue.

Upon inspection of what is in `sys.path` I saw a strange entry

```
'__editable__.<package_name>-<package_version>.finder.__path_hook__'
```

I know that a colleague (who does not have this issue) does not see anything similar and instead has the correct local path to the package.

I should also note that I have the Python extension enabled, which includes the Jupyter and Pylance extensions as well. I have tried re-installing those extensions as well and that did not solve the issue either.

**Edit**.

I will add that I only get this PyLance error in notebooks. If I open a regular Python file then all PyLance features appear to be working as expected.

Comment: Have the same issue with a package I develop. I use a virtual env (named env) and I noticed one thing. My package is called mypackage. If I create a folder called mypackage in .env/lib/ and copy over some actual python modules from the package being developed, Pylance will resolve the import. Currently `pip install -e .` will only create mypackage.xxx.dist-info folder but not a mypackage folder with all the code inside. Other external installed packages have both folders in .env/lib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your VSCode settings.json file

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "<path-to-project-root-of-editable-installed-package>",
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was the solution that worked for me!